# How to check you tube video exist or not with embedded HTML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I am using Embedded HTML for playing video on iOS 5 and it is working perfectly, But if video doesn'n exist then it show blank screen. How can i identify video exist or not ? even in this case webView didFailLoadWithError not getting called. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check for existence of the video using Javascript (see [How can I check existence of a file with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657121/how-can-i-check-existence-of-a-file-with-javascript)) and then (again using JS) if the video exists update the reference in the `<video>` element.

Comment: Thanks pgb for Help, Ill try this and let you know. Thanks